# installing jspdf using npm command

Tags: angular, jspdf

problem: `npm install jspdf` not working

I am trying to install the jspdf in command prompt, but it is not getting installed. Below is the command I tried.

```
npm install jspdf
```

When the above command is fired, it stops below place indefinitely and NO ERROR.

fetchMetadata: sill resolveWithNewModule jspdf@1.5.3 checking installable status

Please let me know if any suggestions.

Thanks
vinod

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution?

Comment: No, i am able to perform in my personal laptop so i installed and copied whole project to my other network

Answer (score 10):

there is a problem with the latest version 1.5.3. try installing a previous version. It worked for me:

```
npm install jspdf@1.4.1 --save
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually we implemented in Java

Answer (score 1):

For some npm dependencies the install process can freeze because of firewall.

Try disabling your firewall or connect to a public network, then run npm install again.

Answer (score 1):

Acccording to it's [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf) you can install the package using yarn.

```
yarn add jspdf
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. Actually jspdf is creating performance issue in IE when there are more pages so we used Itext java library creating PDF from back end

Answer (score -3):

You can follow the official [doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf).

Just type `npm i jspdf --save` in the console and it should work fine.

[image]

Comment: Hi, i am did the same by doing npm i jspdf --save but it is getting stuck and not progessing

Comment: Are you using some proxy / something at work may block some requests? Also, do you see any internect activity on the process of your pc? (Task manager -> tab "Performance", section "Ethernet" (or Wi-fi))

Comment: i also npm install jspdf --loglevel vebose

Comment: I am able to install html2canvas without any issues

Comment: npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/canvg 164ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/stackblur-canvas 102ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/omggif 116ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/html2canvas 122ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/promise-polyfill 137ms (from cache)
[..................] \ fetchMetadata: http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/promise-polyfill 137ms (from cache)

Comment: use `npm install jspdf --save --loglevel vebose` and post a photo on what you get till you get stucked please

Comment: how to attach the screenshot in comments

Comment: npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 9352ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 41ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 1376ms
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/canvg 137ms (from cache)
npm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/omggif 60ms (from cache)
[..................] / loadDep:stackblur-canvas: http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/omggif 60ms (from cache)

Comment: You can't. Just insert an image in the question please.

Comment: It is not allowing me to add i will paste the lines

Comment: C:\Project\MVR\Code\MVR>npm install jspdf --loglevel verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
npm verb cli   'install',
npm verb cli   'jspdf',
npm verb cli   '--loglevel',
npm verb cli   'verbose' ]
npm info using npm@6.4.1
npm info using node@v10.15.0

Comment: npm verb npm-session f16e78b13b5c0e86
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/jspdf 47ms (from cache)
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 12600ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 26ms
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 1510ms
npm http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/omggif 51ms (from cache)
[..................] - loadDep:stackblur-canvas: http fetch GET 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/omggif 51ms (from cache)